# Fade FAB when scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I'd like to fade my FAB when scrolling in my `RecyclerView`. Here what I've done so far but it does not work as expected:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallpaper_tab1, container, false);
    //FAB DISSOLVENZA
    mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) mFloatingActionButton.findViewById(R.id.fabWallpaperTab1);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (dy > 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                mFloatingActionButton.hide();
            } else if (dy < 0 && mFloatingActionButton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                mFloatingActionButton.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

My layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerWallpaperTab1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabWallpaperTab1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_upload" />
```

Comment: What actually is your issue? Is it that you can't show the fab or you have problem hiding it??

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`mFloatingButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

instead of `mFloatingButton.hide();`